# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0' exception when starting Stateful Service

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have created a new Service Fabric application in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.1) and added a new service using the ***.Net Core 2.0 Stateful Service*** template.

When I try to run the service it fails to start correctly and I can see the following exception in the Diagnostic Events:

> Description='Replica had multiple failures during open on _Node_0.
>   API call: IStatefulServiceReplica.ChangeRole(P);
>
> Error =
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException (-2147024894)
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the Nuget package ***System.ServiceModel.Primitives***:

```
PM> Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives
```

Answer (score 4):

An answer which may be useful after a Windows 11 update.

In my case, after an update of Windows 11, the application wasn't working because of this error. I had the error Could not load file or assembly System.ServiceModel, version 3.0.0.0.

After long research, I uninstalled the .net framework and re-installed it and it worked.

For this, I used the programs/Uninstall a program/Add remove windows features.

Unchecked all .net framework cases and click on the Okay button.
After the uninstall process, I checked the same cases and click on the Okay button.

Bingo!

Comment: Facing same issue with many customer systems.

Comment: Re-installing .net framework fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The **System.ServiceModel.Primitives** has what I think is a rather odd bug.  If you are using a DLL with a **System.ServiceModel.Primatives** dependency, then you must also install it as a reference in the project that is using that DLL.  If you do not the DLL will not know where to find it and you get the dreaded "*could not load file or assembly...*"
As Ragtimewilly indicated you can easily add the reference through Nuget.
There may be a better way to do this - but adding it through Nuget will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install version 4.4.4 of **System.ServiceModel.Primitives**. The newest version did not fix the issue for me

> Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives -Version 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using both .NET 8 and .NET Framework 4.8 projects in the same solution, and both projects referenced a .NET Framework 4.8 shared project.

I had to downgrade the .NET 8 NuGet Packages that referenced `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` from using a v8 version to using the latest v4 version, so that all projects would end up targeting the same version of `System.ServiceModel.Primitives`.

e.g. I had to downgrade the `System.ServiceModel.Http` and `System.ServiceModel.NetTcp` NuGet packages from v8.0.0 to v4.10.3 in my .NET 8 project. The .NET Framework 4.8 projects already referenced v4.10.3 of the NuGet package.