# Impersonating a user without a password in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I have a .NET 6 web application that needs to impersonate the current domain user to perform some operations on their behalf.
Users authenticate through OAuth, so all I have is a `ClaimsIdentity` from which I can extract the user's UPN.

**I have a working solution with .NET Framework 4.8. My problem is that I cannot find a way to do the same with .NET 6.**

Below are all the details of the setup and what I tried already.

##### Working solution with .NET Framework 4.8

On the web server I have configured the Claims to Windows Token service (c2wts) to allow the application pool identity to impersonate users.
I have also granted to the application pool identity the following privileges through the local policy editor:

- Act as part of the operating system
- Allow log on locally
- Generate security audits
- Impersonate a client after authentication
- Log on as a service

With this setup, using .NET Framework 4.8 I could impersonate the current user with something like this:

```cs
void WorksWithFramework_4_8(string userUpn) {
    var windowsIdentity = S4UClient.UpnLogon(userUpn);
    WindowsImpersonationContext context = windowsIdentity.Impersonate();
    // Do something...
    context.Undo();
}
```

##### .NET 6 attempt 1: S4UClient.UpnLogon

If I try to call `S4UClient.UpnLogon`, I get this exception:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsTokenService.S4UClient' threw an exception.
> Inner Exception:
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Things I tried that did not work:

- Adding a reference to the package `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545013/system-servicemodel-not-found-in-net-core-project)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the framework as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72046185/15622)

##### .NET 6 attempt 2: WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated

```cs
static void RunImpersonatedTest(string upn) { 
    WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(upn);
    WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, () => {

        // This prints the expected output
        Console.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

        // If I try to access something that actually requires privileges, nothing works...
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\SOME-MACHINE\C$\tmp")) {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    });
}
```

If I use `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated`, as soon as I try to do anything I get an access denied error, or this exception:

> Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

Comment: [By default impersonation doesn't work](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110928-00/?p=9533), since everything that wants to support impersonation needs to do so explicitly throughout the whole stack. This makes it very easy to unintentionally break, unfortunately, so if you have any opportunity to move away from impersonation it would be good to take it. Upgrading to a brand new version of .NET is as good an opportunity as any -- alternatively, it's a good argument for remaining with your current version, or at least for the bits that require impersonation.

Comment: The same operations, on the same machine and running with the same credentials, work on the 4.8 version. If I could avoid impersonation I would, but sadly I cannot. It's still astonishing that there is no way to do this in .NET 6.

Comment: Not so astonishing if you consider that impersonation is a Windows-only thing when .NET Core is very much about multi-platform, combined with the fact that few greenfield projects would need impersonation. I'm not saying it can't be made to work, mind you, just that it's not very surprising that working out all the kinks isn't necessarily high on the priority list.

Comment: FYI `Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\SOME-MACHINE\C$\tmp")` is not a call for impersonation, it is a call for delegation. Which will require multihop and Kerberos...

Comment: Thanks Aron. Bad example most likely, but with the same calls as in the .NET 4.8 version and same account constrained delegation is configured correctly, and things still don't work.
I'm going to create a separate service running on .NET framework in the end.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco I think you've run into the same two issues I did, I've logged the FileNotFound error here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/91771 and the impersonation issue here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93537 - I think these are both just bugs in dotnet 6 which is very annoying as like you I am probably going to have to roll back to .NET framework now...

Comment: @JanMartin thanks for the pointers. Not good news sadly :)